Visual Studio missing SQL Debugging menu option
I have 2 PCs with the same latest Visual Studio Version 17.11.5 and SQL Server Data Tools  17.11.47.0 installed.
Why does one installation have the Execute With Debugger option missing?


edit: I guess someone else the the OP edited this line in...
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.

For this issue, here are suggestions you can check to troubleshoot:
1.Right click .sql file and select open with Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools,Eidtor Selector to see if the Execute With Debugger option shows up.
2.If you right click on the sql editor, can you see these two options?
If you type Alt + F5, will the script executed?
Execute
Execute With Debugger


3.Try to reset the vs settings by simply going over to Tools > Import and Export settings > Reset all settings > Yes or No > General > Finish.
4.Try to create a new query or open a new .sql file to see check if the issue for specified files.
5 . Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions. Ensure that SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is installed and enabled.
6.If the issue persists, i would suggest you to uninstall SSDT and reinstall it or repair your VS from VS Installer.

Removed SSDT, reset settings, installed SSDT, at VS start a message that SQL Debugger was not correctly installed. Tried again, same error. Had the reinstall VS, after that debugging was available.

Okay, glad to hear the issue was resolved. Happy coding;)

Removed SSDT, reset settings, installed SSDT, at VS start a message that SQL Debugger was not correctly installed. Tried again, same error. Had the reinstall VS, after that debugging was available.
